# ERROR :near "initial": syntax error, unexpected initial

Tags: compiler-errors, verilog, system-verilog, vlsi

This is my code, and I get this compile error:

> ERROR :near "initial": syntax error, unexpected initial

How do I fix this error?

```
module pract_wildcardequality();

logic [3:0] a,b;

function void wildcradd(a,b);
begin
if(a==?b)
$monitor ("a %d",a==?b);
else 
$monitor ("a else %d",a==?b);
end

initial begin
wildcardd(4'b010x,
4'b0101);
end
//end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to close a `function` using the `endfunction` keyword.  This is similar to the `endmodule` keyword.

I also fixed a typo which caused another compile error: I changed your function call from `wildcardd` to `wildcradd`.  I'm not sure which name you want, but they must match.

```
module pract_wildcardequality();

logic [3:0] a,b;

function void wildcradd(a,b);
begin
    if(a==?b)
    $monitor ("a %d",a==?b);
    else 
    $monitor ("a else %d",a==?b);
end
endfunction

initial begin
    wildcradd(4'b010x,
    4'b0101);
end
endmodule
```